# Spark Java java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in using classes in artifacte jar

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark-sql

I have created some classes in my maven project and I created a jar file using IntelliJ IDEA artifact. Here is the structure of project:

```
+ProjectName:
----src
    -----main
         ------java
               ------A.B (packages)
                     --------DB
                             BP
                             SP
```

In creating a jar file I just included class BP.
Importing the jar file in a new project and run the following simple code in the main function:

```
import A.B.BP;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        BP temp = new BP("Test");
    }
}
```

It build without error but I got the following error at the runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: A/B/BP
    at Test.main(Test.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: A.B.BP
```

I seemed the classes are not available in the classpath at the runtime.

**Point** I did the same for the classes SP and DFS. I create a jar file and imported into a new project, it ran without any error!

Here is my maven *pom.xml* file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I commented dependencies of other classes.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: How are you running your Test class?

Comment: I just create a java class included main method and run it. I did the same thing for many jar files but I don't know why this one gets error

Comment: There is a possibility that the compile time classpath and run time classpath are not the same? Also check your compile time and run time environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of lack of needed dependencies in *runtime*. The story was, I added `spark-sql` dependency in my current Maven project's *pom.xml* file. It implicitly needed some other spark dependencies like `spark-catalyst` and will get them automatically from Maven reps. So When I run my *Spark-SQL* code in the current project, it worked. When I built my classes as an artifact jar and tried to use them in another new project, in exported jar file it just contains `spark-sql` dependency, not other nested dependencies like `spark-catalyst`! In the compile time Java just checked the first level of dependencies and it saw `spark-sql` is provided and my code compiled successfully. But in the runtime in addition to first level dependencies, Java needed nested dependencies like `spark-catalyst` and they were not provided! so it caused the error! I imported those nested dependencies to the test project in addition to the fat jar and it solved the error!